# Can i modify this search command to ignore binary files?

Tags: shell-script, awk, find, binary

I have this command which gets generated by a little script i wrote called "scan", which I use all the time to look for specific content (variable names etc) inside text files:

```
find "." \
  | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' \
  | xargs grep -n --exclude-dir=.git "<iframe" \
  | awk 'length($0) < 1000'
```

here I'm using it to search for iframe start tags, for example.

The last line is telling it to only consider lines under 1000 characters long, since files with lines that long are generally either binaries or concatenated javascript, which I'm generally not interested in.  (I can turn that condition off with an option if I do want to see  long lines).

Is there a nicer way to modify this to exclude binary files?  Or, would I be better off explicitly listing filetypes I want it to ignore, like .mp4, .mp3, .swf, .jpg, .png etc etc?

Comment: You could simplify the whole thing to `grep -nrI --exclude-dir=git -F '<iframe' . | grep -Ex '.{,1000}'` I think (omit the pipe to the second grep if you don't want the length filter; or add suitable `--exclude=<pattern>` filename conditions instead)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man grep` tells me:

> ```
> --binary-files=TYPE
> ```
>
> If the first few bytes of a file indicate that the file 
>             contains binary data, assume  that  the  file  is  of  type
>   TYPE.
>             By default,  TYPE  is `binary`, and grep normally outputs either a one-line message saying that a binary file matches, or no message
>          if there is no match.  If TYPE is `without-match`, grep assumes that a >binary file does not match; this is equivalent to  the  `-I`
>             option.   If TYPE is `text`, grep processes a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the `-a` option.  Warning: `grep --binary-files=text` might output binary garbage, which can have nasty side effects if the output  is  a  terminal  and  if  the
>             terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.

so it looks like `-I` might work for you? (Mind you, it's entirely possible that `grep` will be confused by any non-ASCII-character early in the file, though.)

Oh, and I think you really don't need that first `gawk`, `find … -exec` should work with that, possibly with the `-0` option to terminate found file names with a null byte.

Comment: That's great, thanks!  Just adding the `-I` option to the grep line reduced my example search from 98 seconds to 22 seconds!  (They don't normally take that long, but i picked a very large folder to search for benchmarking purposes).  cheers